# Is there a way to force RDoc to not style words, which correspond to classes or modules?

Tags: ruby, documentation-generation, rdoc

I am trying to write documentation to one of my classes using RDoc and I have the following problem:

This is my source:

```rb
module Native
  module Facebook
    # Service, which starts(schedules) Native Facebook Fetching Jobs for users with Facebook platform.
    #
    # *IMPORTANT:* <tt>Native::Facebook::StartFetchingJobs</tt> is intended to be called only from <tt>config/schedule.rb</tt>.
    #
    # For example:
    #   # config/schedule.rb
    #   every :day, at: '7:00 pm' do
    #     runner 'Native::Facebook::StartFetchingJobs.call'
    #   end
    #
    class StartFetchingJobs < Service
      # ...

      def call
        # ...
      end

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

This is the screenshot of generated doc:

[image]

Since `Native` and `Facebook` are modules, RDoc highlights `Native` and `Facebook` words in the generated doc (by green text).

So, my question - is there a way to force RDoc to not style words, which correspond to classes or modules?

Comment: Maybe just try to write them in lower case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just precede your module and class names with a backslash.

So, instead of `Native` and `Facebook`, use `\Native` and `\Facebook`.

Documentation can be found [here](https://ruby.github.io/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html#class-RDoc::Markup-label-Escaping+Text+Markup). In `Escaping Text Markup` section.